# Why I can't see onclick property?

Tags: javascript, onclick

When I was exploring StackOverflow's code, I get: [image: devt]
And I tried to get `onclick` event handler. There are the report:

```
> $0.onclick
< null
> $0.parentElement.onclick
< null
```

But `$0.click()` gives me some result (answer is upvoted).
How StackOverflow developers hid it and how to make it by hand, in pure JS?

Comment: Probably a delegated event.

Comment: Take a look at the Events tab on the right side of the source code, the events are added with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), or they're delegated on some ancestor element.

Comment: @Teemu, post it as an answer, and I will mark it as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `.onclick` property is one way to add a click event listener to elements, it's not the only way. Another way is via `.addEventListener()`. When an event listener is added to an element via `.addEventListener()`, the `onclick` attribute/property doesn't update to the event handler function. The `.onclick` property is only set on an element if you're using the `onclick=""` attribute or if the code has set the property `elem.onclick = function() {...}`, which nowdays isn't very often.

Chrome does provide you with a way to find the event handlers on different elements. When you're in your developer tools, you can select the element you're interested in, click "Event Listeners" in the right-hand pane, find the event you're intrested in, in this case that's the "click" event, and then look for your element:

[image: An image showing how to click "event listeners", then "click" and then the element in developer tools]

Your element happens to have an event associated with it, but this might not always be the case. As the comments on your question have pointed out, you can sometimes run into cases where there is no click event handler on your specific element, but rather, it is added to a parent of that element. In this case, when you click on your element, the event propegates/"bubbles" up through the DOM, eventually reaching your parent element with the click event listener. The event handler on the parent can then see what element was originally clicked, and can then perform some actions based on that. This is known as event delegation, and is one of the reasons why you might not always find an event tied to your element even when looking in dev tools.